# listing directory from another directory

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-vista, cmd

So i am currently trying to use the `dir` command from within my `c:/` directory, however, i dont want to see whats in my `c:/`, i want to see something from a sub directory, such as `/users` and such. I am currently running windows vista.

I have tried using the `help` command on the `dir` command (`dir /h`) but it has shed no light on what i am trying to do. I am ultimately trying to do this so that i do not have to do things like the following:

```
cd /the/directory/i/want
dir
cd /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current directory is C:\ and your want to list the contents
of c:\temp, this will list c:\temp on the windows XP cmd utility.

dir c:\temp